# extract only multiple wanted lines in same order from .txt file using python

Tags: python-3.x

Txt File looks like below: I would like to extract only Commit ID & Description in same order. exclude all other info in txt file. Output file should have only Commit ID & Description.

- Commit ID 1 
     user- ABC 
     CR ID - 123456
     Description - adefghjik
     email id - abc@email.com
- Commit ID 2
     user- DEF
     CR ID - 987654
     Description - lokiujyt
     email id - efg@email.com
- Commit ID 3
     user- GHI
     CR ID - 789654
     Description - opiuyt
     email id - lmn@email.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We are here to help you fix your code, not to write it for you. What have you tried so far? Can you show some attempts?

Answer (score 0):

I could able to solve. Below is answer.

```
import os
import re
with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if (line.startswith("Commit") or line.startswith("Description")):
            print(line)
```

Comment: You don't need to import `os` and `re`, and the brackets are not needed for the condition of the `if` statement.